# Azure Active Directory with RDWeb

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, remoteapp

I am currently working with Windows Azure for the first time and looking to set up Remote Desktop Services with multi factor auth, so far i have ....

Sync'd the Azure AD with my domain using Dirsync,
set up the multi factor auth for my sync'd accounts,
setup my remote desktop server joined to my local domain delivering remoteapps over internet

However i cannot seem to find a way of using the Azure AD to log in to my Remotedesk RDweb access. I can see how to add applications into azure, however cannot see how to create a custom application for my RDWebaccess URL

Can anyone point me in the right direction or explain what i need to do or what i'm missing?

Thanks